# Ordinal-valued sheaves as internal ordinals

Tags: lo.logic, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

Let $X$ be a topological space (feel free to add some separation axioms like “completely regular” if they help in answering the questions).  Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal, identified as usual with $\{\beta \in \mathit{Ord} : \beta<\alpha\}$.  Consider the following sheaves of $\alpha$-valued functions on $X$:

- $\mathscr{C}_\alpha$ takes an open set $U\subseteq X$ to the set of continuous functions $U\to\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is given the usual (=order) topology.
- $\mathscr{S}_\alpha$ takes an open set $U\subseteq X$ to the set of upper semicontinuous functions $U\to\alpha$, where “upper semicontinuous” means that $f(x) = \operatorname{lim\,sup}_{y\to x} f(y)$ for all $x\in U$ and of course $\operatorname{lim\,sup}_{y\to x} f(y) := \inf_{V\ni x} \sup_{y\in V} f(y)$ where the $\inf$ ranges over all (open, say) neighborhoods $V$ of $x$ in $U$.
- $\mathscr{N}_\alpha$ takes an open set $U\subseteq X$ to the set of normal upper semicontinuous functions $U\to\alpha$, where “normal upper semicontinuous” means that $f(x) = \operatorname{lim\,sup}_{y\to x} \operatorname{lim\,inf}_{z\to y} f(z)$ for all $x\in U$ (of course, $\operatorname{lim\,inf}$ is defined dually to $\operatorname{lim\,sup}$).

The restriction maps are pointwise restriction in each case.  Since each of these is defined by a local property on functions, they are, indeed, sheaves of sets, i.e., objects of the topos $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$ of sheaves of sets on $X$.

We have $\mathscr{C}_\alpha \subseteq \mathscr{N}_\alpha \subseteq \mathscr{S}_\alpha$ where $\subseteq$ means “is a subsheaf of (for the obvious inclusion maps)”.

**Examples:**

- $\mathscr{C}_\omega$, the set of locally constant $\mathbb{N}$-valued functions on $X$, is the natural numbers object of the topos $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$.  And $\mathscr{C}_n$, for finite $n$, is the $n$-fold coproduct $1+\cdots+1$ of the terminal sheaf.
- $\mathscr{S}_2$ takes an open set $U \subseteq X$ to the set of open sets $V \subseteq U$ (identifying an open set $V$ with the upper semicontinuous function $\mathbf{1}_{U\setminus V}$) with restriction defined by intersection, i.e., it is the subobject classifier $\Omega$ of $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$.  More generally, $\mathscr{S}_n(U)$ is the set of all chains $U \supseteq V_0\supseteq \cdots\supseteq V_{n-1} = \varnothing$ of open sets.
- $\mathscr{N}_2$ (as a subsheaf of $\mathscr{S}_2$) consists of *regular* open sets $V \subseteq U$, and can be identified with the internal subset $\{p\in\Omega : \neg\neg p = p\}$ of $\Omega$.

Each of these sheaves comes equipped with a strict ordering $<$ defined by $f<g$ whenever $f(x)<g(x)$ for *all* $x\in U$.  (There is also a lax ordering $\leq$ defined analogously, and the two satisfy axioms (1)–(6) from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286670/strict-and-non-strict-orderings), and in the case of $\mathscr{C}_\alpha$, even (7).  But I believe $<$ is more interesting than $\leq$.)

Furthermore, note that $<$ is well-founded in the sense that if $\mathscr{P}$ is a subsheaf of $\mathscr{F}_\alpha$ (any one of $\mathscr{C}_\alpha, \mathscr{S}_\alpha, \mathscr{N}_\alpha$) such that “any $f \in \mathscr{F}_\alpha(U)$ for which ‘every $g\in\mathscr{F}_\alpha(V)$ with $V\subseteq U$ such that $g<f$ on $V$ belongs to $\mathscr{P}(V)$’ itself belongs to $\mathscr{P}(U)$” then in fact $\mathscr{P}=\mathscr{F}_\alpha$.  (This is proved by induction on $\alpha$, and, of course, the case of $\mathscr{S}_\alpha$ suffices.  Note that if we had used *lower* semicontinuous functions, I think this would not work, e.g., among the lower semicontinuous $\mathbb{N}$-valued functions, the locally bounded ones form a subsheaf which appears to satisfy the induction hypothesis but not generally its conclusion.)

> **Questions:**
>
> - Can we provide an internal description of $\mathscr{C}_\alpha, \mathscr{S}_\alpha, \mathscr{N}_\alpha$ (i.e., couched in the language of intuitionistic set theory) that makes sense in an arbitrary elementary topos?  (Not demanding, of course, that these objects *exist* in an arbitrary topos: e.g., $\mathscr{C}_\omega$ should be the natural numbers object, which doesn't always exist.  Also, not demanding that the description be “uniform” in $\alpha$: it can iterate “externally” over $\alpha$.)
> - How do these objects relate to the various kinds of intuitionistic ordinals considered in Paul Taylor's paper “Intuitionistic Sets and Ordinals” (*J. Symbolic Logic* **61** (1996) 705–744)?

**Motivation / Meta:** I am mostly trying to get an intuitive image of how intuitionistic ordinals work, and $\mathscr{C}_\alpha, \mathscr{S}_\alpha, \mathscr{N}_\alpha$ are not only objects I can (sort of) visualize but they also seem fairly natural, hence the question.  I am a little confused by the fact that upper semicontinuous functions seem to be necessary to make $<$ well-founded (see above), while lower semicontinuous functions would have made the connection with $\Omega$ more transparent — I may have missed something stupid.  If a closely related object is better behaved, I am interested in answers concerning it.

**Edit (2019-03-21) / Meta:** In a previous edit to this question (see revision history) I thought I had defined a sheaf $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$ of *lower* semicontinuous $\alpha$-valued functions which was better behaved (notably, both well-founded and $<$-extensional; with $\mathscr{T}_2$ being $\Omega$ in the more obvious way $V \mapsto \mathbf{1}_V$ and $\mathscr{T}_\omega$ being *locally bounded* lower semicontinuous $\mathbb{N}$-valued functions).  It turns out my definition was nonsensical, so I'm deleting it.  If I find a satisfactory definition, I'll edit again.  But maybe such an object cannot be defined and that's part of the problem.  Sorry about the noise.

Comment: I should maybe have noted that $\mathscr{S}_\alpha$ is not $<$-extensional (i.e., we can have $\{g:g<f\} = \{g:g<f'\}$ without having $f=f'$). Note sure about the other ones. Not sure whether this is Very Bad or simply bad. Not sure about anything.

Comment: PS: Concerning normal semicontinuous functions and their properties, [Kenneth Hardy's thesis, *Rings of Normal Functions*](http://digitool.library.mcgill.ca/thesisfile73726.pdf) (McGill 1968) is worth looking at.

Comment: I have been asking myself this question (or very similar things) for quite some time ! It seems reasonable (at least from your example) that $\mathscr{S}_{\alpha}$ can be described from $\mathscr{C}_{\alpha}$ as the object of order ideals. That is at least what happens for finite ordinal, I don't quitte see if it is still the case past $\omega$. Understanding the relations between these three objects might already reduce a little the problem. (PS: I think your inclusion of sheaves are in the wrong order ? )

Comment: Doesn't the natural numbers object always exist in a sheaf topos?

Comment: @AndrejBauer It does, but I meant that an internal description of my $\mathscr{C}_\alpha$ et al. could be interpreted in a more general topos and of course the objects might then not exist.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason why you're excluding the case of continuous maps $U \to \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is discrete (so, locally constant maps)? That one seems the most natural to me. We could proceed from a reasonable internal definition of a well-order and "just calculate" what we get. For instance, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate well-founded decidable linear orders.

Comment: @AndrejBauer No real reason. I'm willing to add it to the collection: since my main goal is to get an intuitive grasp of how these objects behave and relate (and whether some are better than others), more is good!

Comment: Is there a reason why this feels to me like the class of names of ordinals when talking about a forcing extensions? In other words, the class of all names $\dot x$ such that $1\Vdash\dot x\text{ is an ordinal}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, this is intimately related, at least in the sense that in a Boolean topos any of my objects should give, as you suggest, the classically-defined ordinal (names), though I'm a bit uncertain about the details. My problem is to picture intuitionistic (or, if you wish, Heyting-valued) analogues of the ordinals and get a grasp on how they behave.

Comment: Well, then you might want to think about Cohen's original definition of forcing, which is intuitionistic in its nature.