# From a constructive perspective, what are the ordinal numbers?

Tags: constructive-mathematics, ordinal-numbers

From a constructive and computational perspective, what are the ordinal numbers?

On the one hand, it seems you can represent ordinal numbers symbolically using something like Cantor Normal Form notation. Then the ordinals are discrete, symbolic entities, and things like "$\leq$" become decidable.

On the other hand, you can represent the ordinals recursively as monotonically nondecreasing sequences of smaller ordinals, and then define an undecidable $\leq$ relation: An ordinal $(\alpha_i)$ is greater than or equal to $(\beta_i)$ if for every element of $\beta_j$ there is an element $\alpha_i$ such that $\alpha_i \geq \beta_j$. I struggle to see how this could be useful though.

nLab also mentions the Plump Ordinals, but I'm not sure what they are.

---

For an application, let $\mathrm{On}$, denote the class of all ordinals. Let $\alpha : \mathrm{On} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a mapping from $\mathrm{On}$ to real numbers. For any finite set $S = \{i_1, \ldots, i_n\} \subseteq \mathrm{On}$ where $i_1 < \cdots < i_n$, define the quantity
$${\mathcal K}_S(\alpha) = \sqrt{\alpha_{i_1}^{2^1} +
\sqrt{\alpha_{i_2}^{2^2} + \cdots \sqrt{\alpha_{i_n}^{2^n}}}
}$$
Say that a real $\mathcal{K}(\alpha)$ is the *limit* of $S \mapsto \mathcal{K}_S(\alpha)$ when for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a finite $S \subseteq \mathrm{On}$ such that for all finite $T \subseteq \mathrm{On}$, if $S \subseteq T$ then $|\mathcal{K}_S(\alpha) - \mathcal{K}(\alpha)| < \epsilon$.

Examples:

- if $\alpha_n = 2$ then $\mathcal{K}(\alpha) = \sqrt{2^{2^1} + \sqrt{2^{2^2} + \sqrt{2^{2^3} + \dotsb}}} = 2\phi$ where $\phi$ is the Golden ratio.
- given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, take
  $$\alpha_n = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $n \neq \omega$,}\\
  x & \text{if $n = \omega$}
  \end{cases}$$
  Then $\mathcal{K}(\alpha)$ is the limit if the sequence
  $x, \sqrt{1+x^2}, \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x^4}}, \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x^8}}}, \ldots$. This is a continued radical which is "transfinite".

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325876/ordinal-valued-sheaves-as-internal-ordinals

Comment: In a different world this would not be a research-level question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, I'm sure it's clear to some, but not to me.  What does your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358594/from-a-constructive-perspective-what-are-the-ordinal-numbers#comment902015_358594) mean?  That this should be common knowledge but isn't?

Comment: What does Cantor normal form have to do with decidability of $\leq$?

Comment: @VilleSalo If you represent an ordinal as a finite expression in CNF, then $\leq$ is clearly decidable. The downside is you can only express ordinals up to $\epsilon_0$ in this way

Comment: Ok. That works only for small ordinals though, usually CNF doesn't "terminate" if you try to open it up recursively.

Comment: Sorry I did not read your comment, you say that yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordinals in constructive mathematics ? (references)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208156/ordinals-in-constructive-mathematics-references)

Comment: @LSpice; Suppose someone asked about the ordinal numbers in classical mathematics, would the question stand a chance? This is not a research-level question, as any PhD student of contructive mathematics will simply know how to use Google to look things up.

Comment: @ogogmad: Could you be a bit more precise about your application, in particular, how is the limit supposed to work? Is it $n \to \infty$? In which case, in what sense is $\Omega$ finite? You fixed $\Omega$ at the beginning and it is not allowed to change, and neither are the finitely many ordinals $i_1, \ldots, i_n$, so there's nothing to compute a limit of. It would help if you were precise about how precisely you quantify things. And what does $[i = \omega]$ mean, what's an Inversion Bracket?

Comment: @AndrejBauer An Iverson Bracket (not an "inversion" bracket) is the notation $[p]$, which equals $1$ when $p$ is true, and equals $0$ when $p$ is false.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I've clarified that it's the limit of $\Omega \mapsto {\Large\kappa}_{i \in \Omega}(\alpha_i)$. I then immediately go on to explain what that means

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don't think your suggestion to use filters is enough

Comment: You'll never have to go beyond the ordinal $\omega_1$, right? Your notation is still quite unintelligible. I will edit your question and please reject my edit if it is completely off the mark, or fix it, or whatever.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Don't need to for my application

Comment: I edited the question so that there aren't any dangling and unspecified variables, unecessasry indices etc. Is my interpretation of what you wrote correct?

Comment: More or less. I'm about to make an edit. Do you mind if I ping you when I'm done to get your opinion of it?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. I edited my answer to explain that you're not looking for anything related to constructive ordinals. What you have is the limit of a net, as known in topology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107263/discussion-between-ogogmad-and-andrej-bauer).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Addressing your first remark: I did Google the topic, but unlike you I don't have decades of experience in this area.

Comment: That remark wasn't a reflection on your asking. It was a reflection on the fact that such a question isn't shot down by the users of MO. This just shows that "research-level" is a very much a social category (which of course is to be expected).

Answer (score 4):

The ordinals in constructive mathematics are not as well-behaved as in classical mathematics. For example, [if they are linearly ordered the excluded middle holds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/incompatible-set-axs.html#ConOrd). There are appropriate substitutes, such as well-founded orders and inductive types. If you told us what you need the constructive ordinals for, we might be able to tell you what to use instead.

There are several possible definitions of ordinals which are classically equivalent but are intuitionistically distinct. For further reading I recommend
the material available on Paul Taylor's web page summarizing his work on [induction, recursion, replacement and the ordinals](https://www.paultaylor.eu/ordinals/). Plump ordinals were defined in "Intuitionistic Sets and Ordinals", available on the web page.

**Supplemental:** If I understand your application correctly, then it has nothing to do with ordinal notations, ordinal representations, or intuitionistic ordinals. It is a case of the [limit of a net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Limits_of_nets) from topology. Specifically, let $D$ be the set of all finite subsets of the index set $I$ of ordinals (from your application), ordered by $\subseteq$. Then $D$ is a directed set, and the number $\mathcal{K}(\alpha)$ is precisely the limit of the map $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(S) = \mathcal{K}_S(\alpha)$.

Comment: OK, what about the representations I proposed in my question?

Comment: From what I understand about your description of an application, you are not looking for any constructive ordinals. Are you familiar with general notions of convergence, such as net convergence and filter convergence? That's where you should be looking, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The purpose of using the ordinal numbers in my example was to define a transfinite sequence, not to define any kind of limit. That said, now I can see that I don't need the well-ordering property of the ordinals, and can just as well use any totally ordered set